# What type of algebra are Valiant's algebras for context-free grammars?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In [General Context-Free Recognition in Less than Cubic Time](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000075800468), Leslie Valiant gives an algorithm for transitive closure of matrices where the matrices are over an algebra $(S, \cup, \cdot, 0)$ where

> the outer operation ($\cup$) is commutative and associative, ... the inner one ($\cdot$) distributes over it and ... $0$ is a multiplicative zero and an additive identity.

Is there a name for such structures, which are generalisations of semirings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the terminology of [nonassociative rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonassociative_ring), we could call this a nonassociative semiring, and indeed Google gives some results for that term with a matching definition.